# How to use static library and module map file with Swift?

Tags: swift, module, xcode9, module-map

I'm trying to include a 3rd party static library in my Swift project. I have these two files, among a few others.

> GoogleConversionTrackingSDK/ACTReporter.h
>   GoogleConversionTrackingSDK/libGoogleConversionTracking.a

I added the `.a` file to the target's "Linked Frameworks and Library" section. I then created a `module.map` file in my project, like this:

```
module GoogleConversionTracking {
    header "../../Libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSDK/ACTReporter.h"    
    export *
}
```

And in Swift files I can now refer to it:

```
import GoogleConversionTracking
```

But I get an error at link time:

> ld: library not found for -lGoogleConversionTracking
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   note: library not found for -lGoogleConversionTracking

How do you fix this? I would like to not use a bridging header, but instead use these module definition files, if possible.

Answer (score 12):

Module map is my synonym for trouble! Bridging headers suck, but they just work in most cases. Anyways, make sure to:

- Configure `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` – a list of paths to be searched by the Swift compiler for additional Swift modules. This tells Xcode where your module maps are.
- Configure `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` – this is a list of paths to folders to be searched by the linker for libraries used by the product. Xcode still needs to know where binaries for your modules are.

Also, you probably want to use the umbrella header, not just header, see [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#id26). I'd also suggest using `modulemap` extension, not sure if `module.map` makes difference, but that's how I remember seeing and using it in most projects.

Omar Abdelhafith has a wicked [blog post](http://nsomar.io/modular-framework-creating-and-using-them) on this matter and it also helps to see [how others do it](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=modulemap+language%3Aswift&type=) when dealing with those kind of things.

Comment: This answer was very helpful! After renaming a group of an existing project SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS pointed to a non-existing group, which caused big trouble.